# Tagging for questions determining site scope

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have questions here in meta tagged as [[on-topic-definition](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition)] as well as ones tagged [[allowed-topics](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-topics)]. Let's pick one, any preference?

Answer (score 3):

Since the FAQ will link to all these discussions, we'll need a single tag for all of them, whether they're on- or off-topic. (We could link to more than one tag, but presenting users with a single tag they can page through seems to be simpler.)

Bicycles.se uses the tag [[on-off-topic](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic)] for this, English Language and Usage uses [[on-topic-off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-off-topic)], for example. I propose using [[on-topic-definition](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition)], since a lot of questions use it already. (We can add [on-topic] and [off-topic] as well if people think it's important to identify these questions as on-or off-topic.)

Comment: I used the [on-topic-definition] tag in my questions because I saw it commonly used on some other meta sites.

Answer (score -1):

[on-topic-definition] would be the tag I'd use for when the question is about what is generally allowed.

I'd use [off-topic] when it is about what is not allowed.

Comment: We need a tag that covers both, so we can link to it from the FAQ.

Comment: At the core these are the same topic.  "Is this allowed or not?"